# Reuse {{$randomInt}} in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

My 1st request is: `GET http://example.com?int={{$randomInt}}`.
I need to run 2nd request (with other tests in it) to the same address, so I need to save generated variable. How can I do it?

I was trying `pm.variables.get("int")` in the "Tests" sandbox after 1st request, but this code cannot see `int` var.

Creating random number in Pre-req. sandbox to 1st request:
`postman.setGlobalVariable('int', Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));` 
doesn't help either, because I need to use this param in the URL, while "Pre-req." block is run after request but before tests.

So how can I generate random var before 1st request and store it to use in 2nd request?

Comment: Do you need to use `{{$randomInt}}` once and then a different value in a 2nd request. The question is slightly confusing and hard to follow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you set this in the `Pre-Request Script` of the first request:

```
pm.globals.set('int', Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))

Or

// Using the built-in Lodash module
pm.globals.set("int", _.random(0, 1000))
```

You will be able to reference it and use the `{{int}}` syntax in any request. If you add this in the first request and then use it in the URL `http://first-example.com?int={{int}}` this value will then persist and you can use it again in a second request `http://second-example.com?int={{int}}`

Each time that `{{$randomInt}}` is used, it will generate a new value at run time.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I need to use already generated variable and not again `{{randomInt}}` for the 2nd time.
So I was using wrong syntax in Pre-req.
Thanks!

Comment: Cool, hope the solution helps. :)