# How to read dynamic request parameter value in postman?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I pass some a random integer in the value of a parameter in the request body -

```
"trans_id":"7q498992029699{{$randomInt}}"
```

What is the best way to get the final value of trans_id param in the Tests tab?

As per my observation, using `{{$randomInt}}` again in the request body gives a different random integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way around is to store it to environment variable while sending the request, using Pre-request-script. And later get same environment variable in your test.

Body:

```
{
    "trans_id": "{{transId}}"
}
```

Pre-request-script:

```
var randomNumber = '7q498992029699' + _.random(0, 1000);
pm.environment.set("transId", randomNumner);
```

Test:

```
var tarnsId = pm.environment.get("transId");
```

Note: `{{$randomInt}}` and `_.random(0, 1000)` both are doing the same thing, it provides random number from 0-1000.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your random int as a variable in the Pre-Request script of your request like this:

```
pm.globals.set('myRandomInt', Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))

Or

// Using the built-in Lodash module
pm.globals.set("myRandomInt", _.random(0, 1000))
```

(I am using a global variable in this example but you can of course use an environment variable if you want to.)

Now you can re-use the variable `{{myRandomInt}}` in your request body and in your Tests tab.

Comment: You can simply use reference link instead of copying the code from another answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184677/4753489